# How to stop video after specific time period?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want my app to stop playing video after specific time period (say 30 sec) and show me a menu of some options i.e. to collapse media-element at the same time. I don't how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DispatcherTimer, set its interval to 30 seconds and in the tick event do your code to stop the video and the timer itself.

Alternatively you can use Scheduler from Rx.